# How to deal with too many notices of DMCA removal for a video sharing service?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, google-ranking, user-generated-content, dmca

We have many daily notices of DMCA removal in our search console.
Our website is a local video sharing service like Youtube.

Many notices of our video URLs(uploaded by users) have not any copyright issues.
Question is:

What should we do?Can we ignore the notices or we should take an action?

Comment: Sorry but the question is too broad as it includes multiple questions and some of those questions would attract opinionated answers, why the question if DMCA effects your rankings has been asked before in various forms, please take a look at [DMCA related questions](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=DMCA).

Comment: But to add... if you do not ACTION DMCA requests then your domain can be seized and disabled by ICANN or similar domain operators. Also, too many DMCA requests damage your domain and not just the page. If you are allowing users to upload content then it is your responsibility to remove pirated content before you receive these requests otherwise expect a penalty, there is no loop hope, if site attracts such content and you do not have the man power then you should NOT be allowing unmoderated content to be published, this is how Google and Bing think.

Comment: @SimonHayter Exactly what should I do?How can take action when I receive DMCA notice and my content violate copywrite rules?My URLs has been de-indexed.So Shall we remove my URLs?setting them to 404?Or adding noindex tag?

Comment: Anyone please answer my above comment.So I can mark it as correct answer

Comment: Could a site have a short grace window where a counter claim can be filed before the video is taken down, or would they lose their protections?

Comment: @jrtapsell I didn't get your comment

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the notices could get you shut down by your Web Host, even if you are "only sharing." Youtube takes down videos all the time due to DMCA complaints, so you could take their lead...  However, it would probably be best to consult an attorney

Comment: Exactly what should I do? Remove those pages with 404 or adding noindex attribute or what?

Comment: Remove them with a 404 or 410.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller What about notices that are not valid?The notices without any copyright problems.We have may daily wrong and invalid notices.We should answer to google for every invalid notices?

Comment: You can file a "DMCA counter notice" in that case.